# Flyway with spring boot overwrites whole DB every time I switch run mode between WAR and IDE run

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

I'm facing very weird issue while integrating flyway DB migration with spring boot application.

When I run the application from executable WAR using command line, it creates new DB at the start-up of application.
Now, If I switch the application run mode to IDE (i.e. run from STS), it again fires all the script from my `db/migration` folder. I can see the `installed_on` column time changes every-time I switch between these 2 run modes. I have tried enabling `baselineOnMigrate` property, but didn't get any effect of it.
Do you think its something related to spring boot embedded tomcat ? because at both run it creates individual tomcat which is embedded.

Please find my spring boot application.properties below:

```
mssql.dbname=issueDB
mssql.password=password
mssql.dbserver=localhost
mssql.port=1501

spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://${mssql.dbserver}:${mssql.port};databaseName=${mssql.dbname}
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=${mssql.password}

spring.flyway.baselineOnMigrate=true
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration/testissue
spring.flyway.out-of-order=true
spring.flyway.baseline-version=1.3
spring.flyway.placeholder-prefix=$
spring.flyway.placeholder-suffix=$
spring.flyway.mixed=true
spring.flyway.cleanOnValidationError=true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose, it could be caused by this property `spring.flyway.cleanOnValidationError=true`. According to the [docs](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/migrate):

> Whether to automatically call clean or not when a validation error occurs.
>
> This is exclusively intended as a convenience for development. Even tough we strongly recommend not to change migration scripts once they have been checked into SCM and run, this provides a way of dealing with this case in a smooth manner. The database will be wiped clean automatically, ensuring that the next migration will bring you back to the state checked into SCM.

May be that you got some validation problems if you are running your application in different ways on the same database and flyway just clean your database and overwrite it with the current scripts state.

Comment: yep that was the cause, Thanks for the support. I have found that checksum mismatch occurs when I am trying to run within IDE and from WAR. Now gradle bootWar target is causing something here. Do you have any idea regarding this ?